# Java, do variables associated with an object persist? BigInteger Example

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm having a bit of trying to figure if the variables used when creating an object persist in Java.

Specifically I'm looking at BigInteger. If I'm reading the code correctly it looks like instead of doing addition etc. on a bit by bit basis the number is broken up into 32bit words which allows for faster operation. What I have not been able to figure out is whether this 32bit word representation and other variables (mag[], signum etc.) have to be created everytime a method is used on a BigInteger or if it somehow they persists in cache and remain associated with their particular BigInteger once it has been created.

Comment: Those are just fields that are kept in memory when any instance of BigInteger is created, there is no cache or magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *guess* you're looking at this code:

```
 1054    public BigInteger add(BigInteger val) {
 1055         int[] resultMag;
 1056         if (val.signum == 0)
 1057             return this;
 1058         if (signum == 0)
 1059             return val;
 1060         if (val.signum == signum)
 1061             return new BigInteger(add(mag, val.mag), signum);
 1062 
 1063         int cmp = intArrayCmp(mag, val.mag);
 1064         if (cmp==0)
 1065             return ZERO;
 1066         resultMag = (cmp>0 ? subtract(mag, val.mag)
 1067                            : subtract(val.mag, mag));
 1068         resultMag = trustedStripLeadingZeroInts(resultMag);
 1069 
 1070         return new BigInteger(resultMag, cmp*signum);
 1071     }
```

The `mag` and `signum` that you refer to are *fields* in each instance of `BigInteger`. They are *not* calculated on demand, they are *part* of the implementation of `BigInteger`. Their very method of access (*not* a function invocation) indicates it's merely accessing a storage location.

Comment: It's code like that I@m talking about yes. I understand now those are the fields that make up the BigInteger and are created as the BigInteger is created or when first needed and persist. What I still don't get is if those fields were instead public how would they be addressed so I could access them. Ideally I'd like to be able to use the private mutableBigInteger and those fields for other methods so I'm wondering if I cut and pasted the entire code and edited to make fields public how could I address them. Probably saying this badly but hope you get the idea.

Comment: @Rhuaidhri Tynan: Don't make fields like that `public` (or, take a time machine back to the 1970s if you're going to do that). You can no longer protect the invariants of your class from abuse. And, you'd have to press me *very* hard to be convinced that making a mutable `BigInteger` class *exposed* to the world is a good idea. `6` isn't mutable, and neither should be `2^57,885,161 - 1`.

Comment: I'm new to OO reading the java tutorials. The one place where mutable BigInts make sense to me is with the bitwise like methods. It seems silly to me to have to perform a N bit operation when I just want to change one bit. I've come up with some maths that makes some large int operations simpler and instead of having to create my own version of BigInt I'm trying to figure out how I can combine my methods with the existing code base.

Comment: The conclusion of the developers of the `BigInteger` API was that for the use cases of `BigInteger`, the benefits of exposing internal implementation details weren't worth the possible confusion that can arise.  (Among other things, immutable objects are generally a _very_ good idea; they're automatically thread-safe, and they're difficult to mess up.)  It's pretty deliberate that you can't mix your code with `BigInteger`.

Comment: I can see the upside and thread safe is great since it means iterative methods can be forked joined without concerns so yes apart from a few instances immutable makes sense but not being able to get access to the fields in this case means a whole lot of code replication and wasted cycles.

Comment: @Rhuaidhri Tynan: No, it's not silly *at all*. Numbers are defined by their *value* not by their identity, therefore they *should* be immutable. `6` is `6`, and you can't mutate that.

Comment: @Jason Your missing the point. 6 is 6 but x can be 6,7 or whatever. When we declare a int value we're saying this is of a fixed type not a fixed value unless we declare it as static. With BigIntegers we don't get the opportunity to do that. As as I've said I can see this makes sense except it some cases where it will lead to a lot of wasted cycles for example when we only want to change a specific bit in the binary representation.

Comment: @Jason: Structuring the class it the way it is also leads to a lot of code replication, they could have kept fields private but still given us a way to access them via a public method which would have addressed all concerns.

Comment: @Rhuaidhri Tynan: I am *not* missing the point. I understand perfectly well what you're trying to do. And I think it's a *bad* idea. If `x` is a storage location holding `Integer`, it *can* hold any value. But it obtains different values *not* through mutation.

Answer (score 2):

Those are just normal object fields -- they're *how* that object is stored.  They're not "created everytime a method is used on a BigInteger" -- what would they be created from?  A `BigInteger` *is* implemented as that set of fields; there's no other magical implementation they're extrapolated from.

Comment: Thats what was confusing me, the BigInteger itself acts as if BigIntegers were represented in two's-complement notation so it looks like it's just an array so I wasn't sure if it consisted of just a two's-complement representation in an array or all those fields. The bit that I still don't get is how that is stored in memory, if the code was changed to make those fields public how would they be addressed. I'm having trouble understanding the java tutorials on this whole area.